No se renderiza el resultado, con React
function App() {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1> hola mundo</h1>
    </section>
  )
}

No sé si necesito meterlo en un props o qué sucede, pero al cargarlo en localhost no se muestra la parte de código de html.

Añade, por favor el index.jsx como código y ademas comprueba que esté importado el .jsx en index.html y la consola del navegador no muestre ningún error.
